# Creating a sorted sqlite-database with python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to create a datebase named "Counts" which keeps track of how many times a spesific email address has sent an email. The data is parsed from a textfile and the database is created using python.

My code looks like this:

```
 import sqlite3
 conn = sqlite3.connect('emaildb.sqlite')
 cur = conn.cursor()
 cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Counts')
 cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE Counts (email TEXT, count INTEGER)''')
 fname = input('Enter file name: ')
 fh = open(fname)
 for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith("From"): continue
    pieces = line.split()
    email = pieces[1]
    cur.execute('SELECT count FROM Counts WHERE email= ? ', (email,))
    row = cur.fetchone()
    if row is None:
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Counts (email, count)
            VALUES (?, 1)''', (email,))
    else:
        cur.execute('UPDATE Counts SET count = count + 1 WHERE email= ?',(email,))
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM Counts ORDER BY count DESC')
conn.commit()
```

The code produces perfectly working database, but it is not ordered. Using the above mentioned

```
`"SELECT * FROM Counts ORDER BY count DESC"`
```

command I can sort the database in the sqlitebrowser. Somehow that doesn't work when integrated in the python code even though I use commit after ordering command.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The command `cur.execute('SELECT * FROM Counts ORDER BY count DESC')` does not reorder the database itself, it just orders the results of the select statement.

More fundamentally, a `SELECT` statement does not modify anything. It just returns a list of the rows you ask for.

If you want to change the order of the rows in the database, you need to use `UPDATE` or `INSERT` commands to do so, but in your case, you probably don't actually want to do this. It is better to just order the results every time using `ORDER BY`.

Because of how sqlite works, it is usually not a good idea to rely on the order the results are stored in the database. More information about how rows are ordered in sqlite can be found in the docs: https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html

sqlite tables use 'rowid' for order by default.